# VS 2013 error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security' or one of its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm getting this error in Nuget Package Manager Console window, please see image attached. I think because of this I can not install an older version of package I need (Umbraco CMS) - during installation similar strange error arises with a bit different messages. I've checked this on different computer - without this error older package is being installed properly.

Tried re-installing Visual Studio 2 times - no effect. I could not achieved clean re-install, new VS instance inherits many plugins and features from previous instance.

Please somebody help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

[image: VS 2013 error message]